# making a symlink based on corresponding file name

Tags: text-processing, ln

I want to create symlinks for my files (**in total 350 files**)

```
cd ./my_files
PD26400a.fixedheader.hs37d5.cram
PD26400a.fixedheader.hs37d5.cram.crai
...
```

I have a text file in which each file name in my my_files directory (column2) corresponds to its old name (columns 1)

```
SAMEA3471108.fixed.GRCh37d5.cram  PD26400a.fixedheader.hs37d5.cram
SAMEA3471108.fixed.GRCh37d5.cram.crai  PD26400a.fixedheader.hs37d5.cram.bai
SAMEA3471112.fixed.GRCh37d5.cram  PD26400b.fixedheader.hs37d5.cram
SAMEA3471112.fixed.GRCh37d5.cram.crai  PD26400b.fixedheader.hs37d5.cram.bai
```

I want to generate symlinks and get this out put

```
SAMEA3471108.fixed.GRCh37d5.cram -> PD26400a.fixedheader.hs37d5.cram
SAMEA3471108.fixed.GRCh37d5.cram.crai -> PD26400a.fixedheader.hs37d5.cram.bai
SAMEA3471112.fixed.GRCh37d5.cram -> PD26400b.fixedheader.hs37d5.cram
SAMEA3471112.fixed.GRCh37d5.cram.crai -> PD26400b.fixedheader.hs37d5.cram.bai
```

how can I do that?

Comment: Do you actually want to ***create*** the symlinks or just to display the output as you show it ?

Comment: I want to "create" symlink

Comment: You use of quotes around the word `create` in your last comment, and the inclusion of the [tag:text-processing] tag, means I still don't know whether you _actually_ want to create symbolic links, or just show the particular output on screen.  Also, you never mention what command creates that output, and what is the text-processing that needs to happen?

Comment: Note: the output resembles what `ls -l` would print, but it seems it shows the opposite to what you described. For me it's somewhat misleading. You may not have had `ls -l` in mind, but still. "What command creates that output?" is a good question.

Answer (score 0):

since you already has the two columns did you've tried awk?

```
echo 'SAMEA3471108.fixed.GRCh37d5.cram  PD26400a.fixedheader.hs37d5.cram' | awk '{print $1, "->", $2}'
SAMEA3471108.fixed.GRCh37d5.cram -> PD26400a.fixedheader.hs37d5.cram
```

You could use something like this, maybe:

```
awk '{ system("ln $1 $2") }
```

Comment: I have 350 files!

Answer (score 0):

```
$ < <(awk 'NF==2 {print "ln -s -T "$1 " " $2}' filein) xargs -0 bash -c
```

where `filein` is the text file containing your two columns.

Edit: added the `-s` flag to the `ln` cmd invocation, assuming you want symbolic links instead of the default hard links.